# Delete long name path folders older than 7 days

Tags: path, long-integer

I need to make a script that it will be delete folders and files(all things), but only older than 7 days. I have a code, but it has a problem when path name is longer than 256 chars. One of the user has a many folders, name lenght equal 303 chars.
Below code works on Windows 10, but has problem on Windows 2008R2(.net 4.7.2) with `\\?\....`

`Get-ChildItem -Path '\\?\c:\test\users' | ?{ $_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Remove-Item  -recurse -force`

And that has problem with long path name:

`Get-ChildItem D:\foler\folder\file | ?{ $_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
Get-ChildItem D:\foler\folder\file | ?{ $_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-7) } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`

Also I try with robocopy. So will be ok any script on powershell, .bat or .vbs.